# Solutions to the equation $a + b - ab/t = t/2$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$a + b - ab/t = t/2$$ 
Where $0 < a < b < t$,
$a,b,t \in \mathbb{N}$
and t is even, ie $t\mod2 = 0$

What are the possible values for a, b for a given t?

For example, if t = 1000, then a = 200, b = 375 is the only solution

I understand that since t/2 is even, then the right hand side is an integer, thus t divides ab, but I can seem to get any further

Comment: Is the question phrased for some specific $t$ or a a general $t$?

Comment: Perhaps a starting point: multiply both sides by $-t$ and add $t^2$ to both sides to get
$$
\frac{1}{2}t^2=t^2-ta-tb+ab\iff\frac{1}{2}t^2=(t-b)(t-a).
$$
This gives $\frac{1}{2}t<(t-b)<(t-a)<t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple transform gives
$$(t-a)(t-b) = t^2/2$$.
We make variable change, with $c = t-a$ and $d = t - b$. 
$$ cd = t^2/2$$. 
Both $c$ and $d$ should be integer in $]t/2, t[$.

Given $t$, then it is just a question of factoring $t^2/2$. The problem might be easier, if $t$ has a brief prime number decomposition.